# Is Facepile bugged?

Tags: plugins, facebook-like, facepile

I'm trying to test out Facepile using a URL that I know my friend has shared. When I look at the Activity Feed using the domain of that URL, I see my friends actions in there. However, when I lookat Facepile, I get a message saying "One person likes this.", but no indication that it's my friend.

Is this known? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you (the website viewer) are not currently logged into Facebook, as unless you are logged in, it cannot check if *your* friends have liked it.